# Magnetic Water Softener

Tags: water, magnetism, water-treatment

I've been asked to install some kind of technology to a building with 40 rooms to soften the water. Browsing through the product catalog I found this so called "Magnetic Water Softener", however theres no description of how it works, how does it make water soft?

Comment: Ostensibly it uses a magnetic field to "pull the ions in the water out" by preventing them to continue flowing after the softening unit. I do not know if this application is proven.

Comment: The wiki claimed it is not proven yet but some studies indicated a substancial decrease in water hardness. So it prevents the ions of the minerals from flowing inside it right? Does that mean it needs to be cleaned afterwards to prevent blockage?

Comment: Pure crank science, as to me.

Comment: It works by pulling money from your pocket. Avoid.

Comment: I would be VERY suspicious of the studies that show any positive results, let alone substantial results, if there is no consensus on feasibility. I agree with Ivan Neretin and Toff Minehardt.

Comment: Surprisingly these have been sold for over 40 years in industry ( petroleum and chemical). But when you try to get an objective measure the streams are too dirty, too hot, too much Cl , and a dozen other excuses.  Generally they only work when a flow is essentially not corrosive.  Don't believe me ; I expect you should be able to search this in NACE , ( I heard at least one paper presented in the 70's).

Comment: One of the most weird things i've read in the product's description is that it never needs maintenance and works for life... Still I don't get it, how should it work in theory?

Comment: It doesn't. Save yourself the effort and future troubles and get an ion exchange based softener (typical home softener) or reverse osmosis system.

Comment: The magnets might have *some* use if there are big particles of iron (pumps breaking down), but it would take mega-gauss field to pull tiny particles of colloidal iron oxides out of the flow. People also put magnets in shoes or bracelets to relieve pain... "There's a sucker born every minute, " attributed to P. T. Barnum.